# Why is the load button unclickable?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Whenever I go into a VAB and try to load a craft, the load button is unresponsive. All other buttons work except for load. Loading crafts that came with mods from clicking on the runway doesn't work either. I've searched online, but I haven't found any results. I have the following mods running in 0.90:

- Tweakscale
- Ferram Aerospace (FAR)
- PlanetFactory Revived
- B9 Aerospace pack
- DarkMultiplayer

How can I fix this? Is it fixable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button is disabled except under two conditions (or both):

- You have saved a vessel previously
- You have enabled the **Allow Stock Vessels** difficulty option

If you didn't enable stock vessels when you started the campaign (it's off by default unless you chose **Easy**), you can enable it from the Space Centre by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> to open the pause menu, clicking **Game Difficulty**, and then enabling **Allow Stock Vessels**.